# Remove user from a group in Intra admin centre

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm unable to remove a user from a group in Intra admin center manually and using the PowerShell command. Error message "Insufficient privileges to remove the selected memberships". The group membership type is Dynamic.

The dynamic membership rule syntax:
(user.accountEnabled -eq true)

Do share your suggestions/resolution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove the user from a group in the Intra admin centre

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I created a group with the name **`group326`** with a dynamic membership type.

[image]

Since I also faced this same issue in the portal. I can't able to remove the user.

[image]

To remove a user from the dynamic membership

***Portal -> Groups -> < your-group-name > -> Dynamic membership rules***

In dynamic membership rule syntax add the below syntax:

```
(user.accountEnabled -eq true) -and (user.userPrincipalName -ne "[user@example.com]").
```

**Portal:**

For example, I added my user principle name in the syntax.

[image]

Once you add your syntax and save the syntax it will automatically remove the user from the group.